# How does Java execution from heap differ from execution from c / c++ stack?

Tags: java, c++, c, heap-memory, stack-memory

In c / c++ local objects are created on the stack, and data is fed from the stack to the cpu registers.

In Java there is no stack, all objects are allocated on the heap, now for pre-written code the size needed for objects can be calculated and instead of having an overkill c c++ style per object heap allocation entire code blocks are laid down at once. This way Java's heap performance is almost as good and virtually comparable to that of the stack in c c++.

My question is how does the program flow from the heap to end up being executed?

Lets assume I run a function that copies the program code into memory, after the program is in the heap memory, and returns the program entry point address, how do I initiate its execution?

Comment: There is a stack in java as well. the objects are allocated on heap, but their "pointers" [references] and the stack trace [method calls hirerchy] are on stack.

Comment: The JVM has two stacks: an evaluation stack, and a call stack.

Comment: If you have a function address, you simply call the function.  It's place in memory makes absolutely no difference.  C++ does that too.

Comment: @Mooing Duck So as long as the function has a valid body of compiled code it will be forwarded to the CPU registers and program flow will initiate?

Comment: @ddriver: code goes to the CPU, but not the registers.  The registers hold data.  Other than that, yes.

Comment: @Mooing Duck - well if I will be calling functions I may very well need to send some data, technically I am wrong but conceptually you got my point. Also, not a native speaker here :) Thanks

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what gets allocated; it's only the *non-static data members* that are created for each object. Code and static data are created just once, when the program starts (in C++) or when the class is loaded (in Java), unless you're doing something unusual like loading a plugin, or generating code at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

In Java there *is* a stack. Just because objects are allocated on the heap doesn't mean that there is no stack. Execution does not happen on the heap, execution is method calls being added to and unwound from the stack, just like the execution flow for C / C++.

Comment: stack and heap are not technically correct to begin with, my question is how execution from the FREE STORE differs

Comment: If they are not the terms you mean, then why do you use them in your question?

Comment: @ddriver: Simple, the data is in free store, code is static, neither on the stack nor in free store, in both C/C++ and Java. (With "static" loosely defined for Java)

Answer (score 4):

> In Java there is no stack

Of course there is a stack.
When you do `new` of course the object is allocated to the heap.
But the reference variable e.g. if it is a local variable it is located on the stack.
Also the stack is used for the function parameters (function frame).

Answer (score 0):

If you speak of performance of heap, it means for Java the performance of its garbage collector (GC), which is depending upon its JIT (Just In Time) compiler -the one dynamically translating JVM byte codes to machine code-.

And GC can be remarkably efficient. Read a good [garbage collection handbook](http://gchandbook.org/), and also Andrew's Appel old paper [Garbage Collection can be faster than stack allocation](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/45.ps)

A well designed GC -with a well co-designed JIT- can allocate things really fast. A generational copying GC will spend a small amount of time on young live objects (so the young objects which are dead are essentially sort-of de-allocated "en masse" for free)

Comment: I think the reason the garbage collector and allocation to begin with are so fast is because objects do not pop with new one by one, but are precompiled into a program block that is allocated within a single pool of memory, and later deleted as such, much faster than it would be to call the OS for allocation of individual objects. I am not a huge fan of garbage collection, I like to collect my own garbage, but this trick same can be used to make c and c++ more dynamics friendly and less static. Just as fast heap performance would be possible by using this approach.

Comment: The trick you describe is exactly what copying generational garbage collector do. And you can code a copying generational GC in C, but it is not fun and requires runtime support and coding conventions. See my Qish garbage collector, or my GC inside my MELT.

Comment: I use RAII and find it very elegant and efficient, but it applies only to dynamically allocated heap objects, not to local code. What I am looking for is a way to dynamically create program blocks and load entire program branches at once, executing them and deleting the entire branches as single objects, since they can be size aware, access aligned and so forth. Sort of achieving interpreted language flexibility at compiled c / c++ performance.